# 70 Permission Denied error in VBA

Tags: .net, vba, com, excel, permission-denied

I have an Excel VBA Application running on Windows Vista. A .Net DLL has been added as a reference in the VBA Application and in the VBA Application, I'm able to use the methods available in the DLL.

Problem: When the same VBA Application is tried on a different machine by other users, they get a "70 Permission denied error". On debug mode, I found that the error occured in the VBA application when we tried to initialize an object of that .Net DLL being referenced.

Other users tried running the same application with Admin privilege, but found the same issue.

I'm pretty sure this is related to authorization. But I don't know where these settings needs to be done. Please help.

P.S. The .Net DLL has been registered using regasm and it is present in the GAC as well. Also, There's no authorization related implementation inside the .NET DLL being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the firewall settings on the machine blocked access to Registry Key that was necessary to run this application. Once the settings were changed, the application ran successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this link by MS

**Topic**: **How To Track "Permission Denied" Errors on DLL Files**

**Link**: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286198

**Edit**: If the link doesn't help then

1) Please show us the exact line which is causing the error.

2) When you say you opened the program with Admin privileges, how did you do that?

Comment: Thanks for the link. When I said Admin privileges, I meant complete Administrator privilege on the machine.